# WSO2AM 2.1.0 fails to load API XML from 1.10.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm experimenting with WSO2AM's upgrade process, so I deployed version 1.10.0 on a fresh machine, created and published a simple API (one POST method), and then followed the upgrade instructions described [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release).

However, when starting 2.1.0 (in the link, "Upgrading the API Manager to 2.1.0", step 4b) in the given order, every time I get the following errors:

```
[2017-04-02 16:53:33,051] ERROR - ClassMediatorFactory Error loading class : org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtResponseHandler - Class not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtResponseHandler cannot be found by synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v10

<long stack trace here, let me know if it's of any value>

[2017-04-02 16:53:33,056] ERROR - ApiDeployer API deployment from the file : /home/gabel/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/admin--VPP_REST_v1.0.xml : Failed.
org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error loading class : org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtResponseHandler - Class not found

<long stack trace here, let me know if it's of any value>

[2017-04-02 16:53:33,062] ERROR - AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer Deployment of the Synapse Artifact from file : /home/gabel/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/admin--VPP_REST_v1.0.xml : Failed!
org.apache.synapse.deployers.SynapseArtifactDeploymentException: API deployment from the file : /home/gabel/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/admin--VPP_REST_v1.0.xml : Failed.

<long stack trace here, let me know if it's of any value>

[2017-04-02 16:53:33,067]  INFO - AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer The file has been backed up into : NO_BACKUP_ON_WORKER.INFO
[2017-04-02 16:53:33,067] ERROR - AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer Deployment of synapse artifact failed. Error reading /home/gabel/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/admin--VPP_REST_v1.0.xml : API deployment from the file : /home/gabel/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/admin--VPP_REST_v1.0.xml : Failed.
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: API deployment from the file : /home/gabel/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/admin--VPP_REST_v1.0.xml : Failed.

<long stack trace here, let me know if it's of any value>

Caused by: org.apache.synapse.deployers.SynapseArtifactDeploymentException: API deployment from the file : /home/gabel/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/admin--VPP_REST_v1.0.xml : Failed.

<long stack trace here, let me know if it's of any value>

[2017-04-02 16:53:33,083]  INFO - DeploymentEngine org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: API deployment from the file : /home/gabel/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/admin--VPP_REST_v1.0.xml : Failed.
```

Of course when I'm done executing all the commands in the given order and go to the publisher, the API called VPP_REST isn't there. What am I missing?

The system:

- OS: Ubuntu Server 14.04 64-bit
- JDK: 1.8.0_121

Answer (score 0):

Run the apim200_to_apim210_gateway_artifact_migrator.sh  script as given in step 5 and then perform the step **4b**. (So it'll perform the class name migration which needs to be happen in synapse before the DB migration)